# how to simulating the message pump mechanism in mfc dialog based application?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I want to know how can I simulate the mfc message pump in my dialog based application.
In my application I have one base class as MyDialog. by using this base class I am deriving different kinds of dialogs depending on my requirement. for ex: dialog to get user credentials, dialog to get the folder path for installing program etc. Now the problem is I am trying to show or hide some of the options(controls) on the dialogs on certain conditions. here showwindow() works fine for showing the controls but when I use them to hide the controls It doesn't work at all. But If I minimize or maximize the app ,It works fine. I feel that the window is not getting refreshed (refresh happens when it minimizes or maximizes). why? To make it work I want to create my own message pump. thanx in advance

Comment: UpdateWindow, InvalidateRect, InvalidateRgn will all force a repaint of your dialog/window

Comment: Clearly you already have a message pump operating or you would not be able to minimize and restore the dialog.  You get one from the dialog's DoModal() method.  You will need to document your question better, at least post the code that tries to hide a control.

Comment: AfxPumpMessage() simulate MFC message pump but I doubt your problem related to it, because DoModal() do this for you.